# What is "({})" in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, botkit

I am learning JavaScript / Node.js. Looking at [`bot.js`](https://github.com/howdyai/botkit-starter-web/blob/master/bot.js) from [`botkit-starter-web`](https://github.com/howdyai/botkit-starter-web) line 33, it shows:

`var db = require(__dirname + '/components/database.js')({});`

My question is, what is `({})` represent in that line? I can't Google the answer for it.

Comment: Presumably, the `require` returns a function, which is then called with an empty object.

Comment: If you look at the [file](https://github.com/howdyai/botkit-starter-web/blob/master/components/database.js) you can see the function: `module.exports = function(config) { ... }` The parameter `config` is never used, so you can pass whatever. The author decided to pass an empty object literal.

Comment: All your comments are super helpful, thank you for helping me!

Answer (score 4):

`require(...)` is used to load a module, the return value of `require` is the module, which can be any javascript value (depends on the module being loaded).

In this case it is presumed to be a function.

Adding `({})` is calling that function and passing an empty object `{}` as the first and only argument.

The return value of that function call, being stored in the variable `db`.

It is equivalent to doing this:

```
var database = require(__dirname + '/components/database.js');
var db = database({});
```

Answer (score 0):

At the first you know in database.js exists this code :

```
module.exports = function (object) {
  // . . .
  // some thing on object
  return object;
};
```

when you require this JS file you can send to above function object data (empty or not empty)

```
var db = require(__dirname + '/components/database.js')({});
```

Answer (score 0):

When a module is loaded ( In other words load a javascript file using require(..) ), it returns whatever is assigned to module.exports, for example

```
    //javascript file add.js 
      module.exports = function(a,b){
        return a+b;
      }

    //Usage in app.js
      var add = require("add.js");
      var result = add(2+2);//result would be 4
    //Similarly 
      var result = require("add.js")(2+2);//result would be 4
```

In your case database.js returns a function in its module.exports and that function takes one paramter which is an object.

`var db = require(__dirname + '/components/database.js')({});`

In the above snippet you are passing an empty object to the function.The creators of database.js have given you options to customize some values, something like this

```
var db = require(__dirname + '/components/database.js')({
   port:3306,
}); 
//or 
var options = {};
options.port = 3306;
var Database = require(__dirname + '/components/database.js')
var db = Database(options);
```